# Edit file names as text file

Tags: finder

Is there a way to select multiple files and edit their file names as a list in a text editor?

I'm asking because I want to copy the names of x files over to another folder containing the same number of files. Being able to edit the file names as a text file would be the most convenient way to do this

Which tools permit to manipulate file names as within a text editor?

Comment: Does the target directory contain the same *number* of files, or files with the same *names* as the files in the source directory? How exactly do you want to rename the files, there are ways both in Finder and in `bash` to batch-rename files.

Comment: How does renaming and copying fit together here, seem to be two different operations?

Comment: Yes there is at least an answer to your original question: it's the Dired mode of `Emacs` https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode.

Comment: @dan Feel free to turn your comment into an answer, maybe with some more details.

Comment: You can tried to change the depiction of the finder and make it similar to a List. One the one hand I now a for loop is the comfortable way

Comment: The easiest way I've found to do this so far is using the dired mode of Sublime Text (I think you need to install a package to use this). Plus the personal advantage for me of being able to use Sublime Text instead of Emacs